# How to cache service code from URLClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader

I have to write a Java library that will need to be embedded in various run-time environments (some web services, desktop applications, even possibly in an Oracle database JVM).

It is important that the library run in the JVM of the application that uses it (e.g., I can't just make all the apps call a web service that uses this library).

It is also important that every application running the library runs the same version of it, as the library will be enforcing business logic that must be applied consistently across the enterprise.

Finally, some of the applications using the library are customer facing and have demanding up-time requirements.

**Goal: I want to load a Java library from a central network location, but also cache it locally, to be used in the event that that central location is unavailable**

**Question: can I do this somehow by writing a custom class loader that will search first on a network URL and, if found, load the class and save it locally and, if not found, load a previously locally saved version of the class? **

I don't know everything about classloaders and I am concerned about a few things.  The location of the locally saved (cached) classes would probably not be in the CLASSPATH of the JVM.  Would that be a problem?  What other factors would make this approach problematic / unworkable?

Comment: The first question that comes to mind is why can't you call this shared code as a webservice, as this would address most if not all of your needs (instead of trying to implement a solution that could be far more complex)?

Comment: @KevinHooke We would have liked to, but some of the calling applications have very high performance requirements that cannot be met if a network round-trip is involved every time the logic must be invoked, which is quite often.  There are other reasons as well.

Comment: Just a thought(I may be wrong completely)..You can have own maven repository(nexus)  where library can be kept. And other application can use that library as maven dependency.  It will solve versing issue among different applications.

Comment: @ShaunakPatel for building each app with the shared dependency, yes this will definitely work, but not for the requirement that the code needs to be loaded from a shared location at runtime.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak how often would the shared code change? Instead of loading the shared code dynamically, could you push regular updates to the deployed applications when ever there's an update? I'm thinking how you could avoid this need for loading the code at runtime from a remote location as that's a more difficult solution, as there could be other simpler options you could consider?

Comment: @KevinHooke Once it is stable, the code should change infrequently -- maybe once or twice a year.  The organization I work in is capable of weighing the benefits and complexity of a completely dynamic solution vs other, simpler solutions.  I'm really just interested right now in knowing the feasibility and dangers of the dynamic, class loader solution I outlined in my question.

Comment: Java Web Start would have helped with pushing updates to your desktop apps, but unfortunately it was deprecated in Java 9 and removed completely in Java 11, similarly for Applets which could load classes from a remote source.

Comment: What do you mean with “a regular class loader”? Java’s public API does not offer any other loader than a `URLClassLoader`, which handles both, network protocols and the `file:` protocol.

Comment: @Holger Sorry, you're right.  I've edited my question.  I hope it is clearer now.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you really considering to load each class through a new network connection? No one does such inefficient thing in practice. When you specify a url to a jar file, the `URLClassLoader` will download the file once behind the scenes and load the files from the local copy. In this regard, there’s no difference to an application which opens a network resource at the beginning, to check for a new version and download it when needed, to always proceed with the (potentially updated) local copy afterwards. Depending on the JRE, you may even have such a cache management behind the scenes already.

Comment: I want to reload all the remote classes from the network through a single connection each time my application starts up.  Are you saying if my application loads a class from a URL today it will go across the network but if I start the application again tomorrow it will load the class locally since it already has it?

Comment: I just come across this, I haven't used it, but as a replacement to Java Web Start this may offer some features to solve part of your app distribution problem: https://github.com/threerings/getdown